# validaciones en tiempo real en rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validación

Buenos dias, como podria realizar la validación de un text_field en tiempo real con js en rails?
Tengo mis validates en mi modelo, y las validaciones y vista de errores por campo se realizan pos submit, pero como lo hago para que me valide en el campo mismo sin tener que mandar  submit antes. Saludos
[actualizado]
He probado con la gem Judge, pero no me funciona, dejo el codigo:

```
#views/employees/new.html.erb

      <div class = "panel panel-primary">
        <div class = "panel-heading">
         <h3> Registro de Empleado</h3>
     </div>
<%= render 'form', employee: @employee %>
</div>
#views/employees/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(employee, :builder => Judge::FormBuilder) do |f| %>
                <div class="row row-no-top">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="field">
                  <div class="form-group <%= @employee.errors[:legajo].any? ? " has-error has-feedback" : "" %>">
                       <h1><%= f.label :legajo, "Legajo" %></h1>  
                          <%= f.text_field :legajo, :validate => true, autofocus: true,requiered:true, :class=>"form-control input-sm " ,placeholder: "Legajo" %>  
                                <%if @employee.errors[:legajo].any? %>
                                        <span class="glyphicon  form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <p class="bg-warning"><%= @employee.errors[:legajo].to_s[/\w([^"]*)/] %></p>
                                <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>

<% end %>

#models/employee

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    validates :legajo, :name, :last_name,:document_number,  presence:  { message: "Campo obligatorio" }
    validates :legajo, uniqueness: { message: " El legajo ya existe" }, on: :create
    validates :legajo,  numericality: {  message: " Se permite solo numeros enteros",only_integer: true }
    validates :legajo, length: { is: 5, :message => "Debe tener 5 digitos" }
    validates :legajo, uniqueness: { message: " El legajo ya existe" },  on: :update
end

#assets/javascript/application.js
        //= require underscore
        //= require json2
        //= require judge
        ...
#config/routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
mount Judge::Engine => '/judge'
...
end
```

[image: error que aparece p el usuario al querer guardar los datos]

Comment: `...pero como lo hago para que me valide en el campo mismo sin tener que mandar submit antes.` La respuesta depende de como se manda el formulario, Agrega un ejemplo del HTML (reducido por favor) y el codigo javascript que uses para enviarlo (si usas alguno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a las gemas [judge](https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge) o [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)

Yo he usado la primera y funciona bastante bien.

Por ejemplo para un modelo típico Usuario

```
 # usuario.rb
 class Usuario
   validates :nombre, presence => true
   validates :apellidos, presence => true
 end
```

Al construir los formularios de creación de esta forma

```
form_for(@usuario, :builder => Judge::FormBuilder) do |f|
  f.text_field :nombre, :validate => true
  f.text_field :apellidos, :validate => true
end
```

te genera un formulario parecido a esto

```
<form method="POST" action="/usuarios" id="new_usuario">
  <input type="text" data-klass="Usuario" data-validate="[{'kind':'presence','options':{},'messages':{'blank':'Nombre no puede estar vacío'}}]" id="usuario_nombre">
  <input type="text" data-klass="Usuario" data-validate="[{'kind':'presence','options':{},'messages':{'blank':'Apellidos no puede estar vacío'}}]" name="usuario[apellidos]" id="usuario_apellidos">
</form>
```

Muchos más detalles y funcionalidades en la web de judge

---

**UPDATE**
Si quieres que te valide los campos antes de hacer el submit, puedes añadir, por ejemplo, una clase a todos los campos que quieras validar. Yo la he llamado "validation" y luego uso la función validate que proporciona la gema judge

```
form_for(@usuario, :builder => Judge::FormBuilder) do |f|
  f.text_field :nombre, class: "validation", :validate => true
  f.text_field :apellidos, class: "validation", :validate => true
end

$(function() {
 $('.validation').on('input select', function() {
    judge.validate($(this)[0], {
        valid: function(element) {
                eliminaMensajeError(element);
        },
        invalid: function(element, messages) {
            muestraMensajeError (element, messages);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Los métodos eliminaMensajeError y muestraMensajeError son propios y lo que hacen es resaltar el campo en rojo en error y dejarlos en verde cuando están ok

Comment: Gracias por responde. Estoy probando dicha gema, pero no realiza la validación en el momento de tipear en el campo, o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Si puedes, haz un update de la pregunta incluyendo todo lo que puedas de tu código y le echamos un ojo.

Comment: Buen dia, ahi actualice con el codigo. saludos.

Comment: sandovalgus he añadido lo que hago yo para validar antes de submit

Comment: funciono de maravilla, una ultima consulta, como resolviste el tema de uniqueness, seguir las instrucciones como dice la documentación pero no me funciona. me sigue arrojando " not allowed", con las demas validaciones funciona bien. saludos

Comment: @sandolvagus Parece que es un problema que solo ocurre en desarrollo [enlace] (https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge/issues/24). Yo no he conseguido resolverlo por el momento.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto te sirva. Básicamente está llamando la función cada vez que se "suelta" la tecla. Es decir, después de cada caracter ingresado.

Este código lo puedes poner en `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, pero sería mejor que hicieras un archivo en esa misma carpeta, por ejemplo: `app/assets/javascripts/validacion.js`.

> Nota: Asumiendo que estás utilizando la gema Turbolinks (turbolinks viene en automático incluida en cada nuevo proyecto de rails salvo que lo hayas creado con la bandera `--api`) En Rails 4 generalmente utilizábamos `'page:load'`, pero a partir de Rails 5 (Turbolinks v5) es común utilizar `'turbolinks:load'` al iniciar con tu js. Puedes encontrar más detalles sobre esto en la documentación oficial de [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events).

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  // en lugar de '.input' será la clase o id que identifique 
  // al campo que quieres validar
  $('.input').on('keyup', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {

      // ejemplo de un Regex para validar el formato de un email
      var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

      if(emailRegex.test($('.input').val()) == true) {
        // lo que quieras que suceda si pasa la validación
      }
      else {
        // lo que quieras que suceda si NO pasa la validación
      }

    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar http://rubular.com para crear/validar tus regex (regular expression)

Comment: `turbolinks:load` no depende de si se está usando rails 4 o 5, sino de si se está usando o no la gema de turbolinks

Comment: Como `turbolinks` está en las gemas que Rails incluye por default estoy asumiendo que si la usa, y totalmente de acuerdo en que si la quita del proyecto no hace falta mayor especificación, sin embargo, a partir de rails 5  [los nombres de los eventos cambiaron](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/9#issuecomment-184717346), y así como cuando en muchos casos utilizábamos `page:change` ahora utilizamos `turbolinks:load` en muchos de ellos. Gracias por el comentario y agregaré estas notas para mejorar la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Dependiendo de tus necesidades y como de complejas quieres que sean las validaciones, en lugar de comprobarlo en javascript, podrías hacer un petición AJAX al servidor, hacer las validaciones allí y dar un respuesta .js
Así podrías reutilizar las validaciones que tienes en el modelo y no tendrías que tenerlas duplicadas.

Comment: de esta forma que sugerís, como podría validar que un numero de documento (por ejemplo) sea único (no ingresar repetidos). saludos

Comment: si yo utilizo simple form como seria?

Answer (score 0):

Depende de tus necesidades, tienes variadas opciones.
Lo mas facil de implementar es usando [la validation api de html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation), aunque aún no es soportada del todo por algunos exploradores actuales. También existen varias librerías js que te pueden ayudar a validar tus formularios, como [ParsleyJS](http://parsleyjs.org/) o [validate.js](https://github.com/rickharrison/validate.js)